# How do i separate this code into two classes? (Guessing Game Code)

Tags: java, class

I wrote the code for a class, and turned it in. It works, but the teacher returned it to me because it is one class instead of a main and a separate class. I have no idea how to go about separating the code. Would I have to rewrite the entire thing, or is there an easy method?

here is my code:

```
package numberguess;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class guessmain 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int answer = rand.nextInt(100);
    answer ++;
    int tries = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    int guess;
    boolean win = false;

    while (win == false)
    {
        System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 100");
        guess = input.nextInt();

        if (guess > 100)
        {
            System.out.println("Your guess is out of the range");
        }
        else if (guess < 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Your guess is out of the range");
        }
        else if (guess == answer)
        {
            win = true;
            tries++;
        }
        else if (guess < answer)
        {
            System.out.println("Your guess is too low");
            tries++;
        }
        else if (guess > answer)
        {
            System.out.println("Your guess is too high");
            tries++;
        }

    }

    System.out.println("You Win!");
    System.out.println("It took you " + tries + " tries");
}
}
```

(I hope this is all formatted correctly; this is my first question here)

Comment: There's a code-review site on teh Stack Exchange, while it's a really simple program, several of the answers below discuss the separation of responsibility which would be a good addition to your project.  I think my answer will sooth your angry professor's qualm but you could go there and ask about the best way to separate these behaviours to learn some better Software Engineering practices.
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a game logic class like

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessLogic {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean win;

    public boolean guess() {
        System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 100");
        int guess = input.nextInt();
        int answer = new Random().nextInt(100);
        win = false;
        if (guess > 100) {
            System.out.println("Your guess is out of the range");
        } else if (guess < 1) {
            System.out.println("Your guess is out of the range");
        } else if (guess == answer) {
            win = true;
        } else if (guess < answer) {
            System.out.println("Your guess is too low");
        } else if (guess > answer) {
            System.out.println("Your guess is too high");
        }
        return win;
    }

}
```

And a main class like

```
public class GuessMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GuessLogic guessLogic = new GuessLogic();
        int tries = 1;
        while (!guessLogic.guess()) {
            tries++;
        }
        System.out.println("You Win!");
        System.out.println("It took you " + tries + " tries");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Classes are useful for separating 'concerns,' or problems, into different sections of code.  Your teacher wants you to find at least two problems and tease them apart into separate classes.

Problems that jump out at me are

1. Finding a random number for the right answer
2. Getting input from a user in a loop until the guess is right
3. Counting the number of guesses it takes for the user to guess correctly
4. Displaying instructions and the 'You Win' message
5. Determining the proper output for each guess.

Problem 5 is currently taking up the most room in this function, so maybe it's the first one we should tackle.

Your main function might look something like

```
int answer = rand.nextInt(100);
guessResponder = new GuessResponder(answer);

do {
    guess = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println(guessResponder.respond(guess));
} while (guess != answer);
```

This has moved the concern of calculating the output into a separate class, the `GuessResponder`.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, create one class called Calculate and create a method   calculateNumber pass the input which you get from user

**Tip**: Change your class name to First letter capital **Guessmain**

package numberguess;

```
     import java.util.Random;
      import java.util.Scanner;

        public class guessmain {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Calculate calculate = new Calculate();
    calculate.calculateNumber(input);
}

    }

     class Calculate {

void calculateNumber(Scanner input) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int answer = rand.nextInt(100);
    answer++;
    int tries = 0;

    int guess;
    boolean win = false;

    while (win == false) {
        System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 100");
        guess = input.nextInt();

        if (guess > 100) {
            System.out.println("Your guess is out of the range");
        } else if (guess < 1) {
            System.out.println("Your guess is out of the range");
        } else if (guess == answer) {
            win = true;
            tries++;
        } else if (guess < answer) {
            System.out.println("Your guess is too low");
            tries++;
        } else if (guess > answer) {
            System.out.println("Your guess is too high");
            tries++;
        }

    }

    System.out.println("You Win!");
    System.out.println("It took you " + tries + " tries");
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

In main method, there are 2 logics:

1. Generate a random for answer
2. Do Guess and print information.

You can put them into a Class such as Guess and put these 2 logics into methods.

Like,

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Guess {

private int answer = 0;
int tries = 0;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int guess;
boolean win = false;

public Guess() {
    answer = generateRandomNumber();
}

private int generateRandomNumber() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    return rand.nextInt(100) + 1; // 1 ~ 100
}

public void doGuess() {
    while (!win) {
        System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 100");
        guess = input.nextInt();

        if (guess > 100) {
            System.out.println("Your guess is out of the range");
        } else if (guess < 1) {
            System.out.println("Your guess is out of the range");
        } else if (guess == answer) {
            win = true;
            tries++;
        } else if (guess < answer) {
            System.out.println("Your guess is too low");
            tries++;
        } else if (guess > answer) {
            System.out.println("Your guess is too high");
            tries++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("You Win!");
    System.out.println("It took you " + tries + " tries");
}
}
```

then it is very simply to create an instance of Guess and call corresponding method.

```
public class guessmain {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    new Guess().doGuess();
}
}
```